# Codename One toolbar sidemenu issue

Tags: codenameone

I created a list using table layout which contains checkbox and message.The list is scroll-able . When i scroll down everything works fine,Where as when i check the check box and scroll down the toolbar side menu is expanding.
My requirement is to open the toolbar sidemenu only on the sidemenu toogle button click other than any click on the screen side menu should be in close mode.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible test case for this

Comment: «My requirement is to open the toolbar sidemenu only on the sidemenu toogle button» -> Have you tried to insert in the `init()`: `Toolbar.setEnableSideMenuSwipe(false);`?

Comment: Yes,It worked like a magic.Thanks